# Numpy fromfile io.UnsupportedOperation

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

When I try to read from a binary file using `numpy.fromfile`, I get an error message saying `io.UnsupportedOperation: seek`

I am using `Python 3.7.1`

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as fin:
    prolog = np.fromfile(fin, dtype=np.int32, count=15)
```

Comment: Works fine on my machine.  Is this your real code?  What platform are you on?

Comment: please post the complete error message (the entire stack trace).

Comment: I am on a windows machine.
This is the full error message
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 215, in <module>
    test=read('binary.txt',False)
  File "test.py", line 19, in read
    prolog = np.fromfile(fin, dtype=np.int32, count=15)
io.UnsupportedOperation: seek`

Answer (score 1):

This is simpler and should definitely work:

```
prolog = np.fromfile(filename, dtype=np.int32, count=15)
```

Comment: already tried that but it gives me an error message as well
`prolog = np.fromfile(filename, dtype=np.int32, count=15)

AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'flush'`

Comment: Put this code into a new Python script by itself.  Do you still get that error?

Comment: that is correct, it works alone.  I have to revisit the rest of the code and change it because chances are the problem comes from there

Comment: Right, so your problem is some other part of your code (which you haven't shown) is corrupting your Python environment.  Perhaps by replacing the global name `file` or `open` with something of your own.